# Using reflection to find all classes in an assembly that contain an interface by name

Tags: c#, reflection, thrift

I am working on an implementation of Apache Thrift, all of the service class that thrift generates contain a nested interface called Iface.

I have some additional code that takes what thrift generates and builds a page object pattern based on a naming convention.

What I need to be able to do is, using reflection enumerate all classes within the generated assembly that have a nested interface named Iface.

All of this code was previously implemented with protobuf.net  and Google protocol buffers, we are making the switch for more consistent multi language support.

With the protobuf implementation we used this line to find the correct services:

```
_inputDll.GetTypes().Where(x => typeof(IService).IsAssignableFrom(x) && x.Name != "Stub")
```

this structure no longer works as there is no one determining interface within thrift.

Here is an example of the Thrift generated code that I am attempting to search:

```
 public partial class ServiceA {
    public interface Iface {
      Thrift.ActionResult SetupPreferences(Thrift.BillingPreferencesInfo info);
    }
    // Thrift implementations
}

 public partial class ServiceB {
    public interface Iface {
      Thrift.ActionResult SetupAddress(Thrift.AddressInfo info);
    }
    // Thrift implementations
}
```

Comment: Specifically with this implementation I have not tried anything as I have no clue how to proceed since this is multiple different interfaces that I don't have access to get the type of, I am going to add  a few more details to the question.

Comment: By a "nested interface" do you really mean an interface declaration within the scope of a class, or are you using the word "nested" instead of "implement"? You'd better provide a sample class.

Comment: Nope I really mean an interface declared within a class. Its the one downside of thrift that I've come across.

Comment: I still try to find out what you want to achieve by that? What is the idea behind? In particular, why you want to use reflection to find an specific Thrift interface?

Comment: The thrift implementations are used for Ui Automation testing and based on the name of the services we have defined in thrift we have some code that generates additional code to create a page object pattern or state machine. So that whoever is writing tests need not know about all the services and what actions are possible at each moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the source classes look like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public interface IFace { … }
}
```

then your query needs to make use of [`Type.GetNestedType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kekdz4kb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
someAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && t.GetNestedType("Iface") != null)
```

Comment: Awesome, at first glance this should work will accept as soon as I test it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's a bit old code but it works:

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.List<Type> GetTypesImplementingInterface(string interfaceTypeName, string assembliesNameStartWith)
    {
        var returnTypes = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Type>();

        var list = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().Where(referencedAssembly => referencedAssembly.FullName.StartsWith(assembliesNameStartWith, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();

        try
        {
            returnTypes.AddRange(
                from ass in list
                from t in ass.GetTypes()
                where (TypeImplementsInterface(t, interfaceTypeName))
                select t
            );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceWarning("GetTypesImplementingInterface:{0}:interfaceTypeName:{1}:assembliesNameStartWith:{2}",
                               ex.ToString(), interfaceTypeName, assembliesNameStartWith);
            returnTypes = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Type>();
        }
        return returnTypes;
    }


    private static bool TypeImplementsInterface(Type theType, string interfaceName)
    {
        Type interFaceType = theType.GetInterface(interfaceName, true);
        return (interFaceType != null);
    }
```

Comment: The problem is the classes I'm looking for don't implement any interface

Comment: `from t in ass.GetTypes()`... What does this really return? :)

Comment: The types in the assembly or the types of booties :P